# How can I reference an object in a class method without passing it as an argument?

Tags: python

I'm writing a module to make requests to a work-related website easier. I have one class that initializes the session and has the URL as a variable. I wrote an abstract class to encapsulate the logic of the requests, and one subclass for each of the data-types. Ideally, most of the methods should be class methods, so I can call them by writing `module.subclass1.get(params)`. My problem is that all of these methods need a session, and an URL to make the requests, and I can't figure out a good way to implement this. My code is looking something like this at the moment.

```
#This class I make an instance of, to have the session and url at hand.
class Website:
    def __init__(self, username, password, url):
        self.session = getSession(username, password)
        self.url = url

#The abstract class that handles the requests
class AbstractClass(abc.ABC):
    classvar1 = ""
    classvar2 = ""

    @classmethod
    def get(cls, website, params):
        website.session.get(website.url + cls.classvar1, params)

class Subclass1(AbstractClass):
    classvar1 = "Something else"
    classvar2 = "Something else"
```

Some of my (suboptimal) solutions are:

#### 1. Passing an instance of Website as an argument to the class methods

This works and is what I do for now, but I would have to pass the website object as a parameter all the time.

All calls would end up looking like this:

`module.subclass1.method(website, params)`

#### 2. Making the website object a class variable in the abstract class.

This works and makes the method calls look pretty:    `module.Subclass1.get(params)`   But it seems like very bad practice, and I would like to always have to specify a username, password, and URL, so different scripts can use different logins and so I can change the URL to test or prod environment.

#### 3. Initializing all the subclasses with a website object in the Website class

This also makes the method calls look pretty `website.Subclass1.method(params)`, but I would have to initialize every single subclass in the Website `__init__` method, and would have to change the abstract class to add an`__init__` method that takes a Website object as an argument.

Is there any smarter way to accomplish this? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Option 2 doesn't look so bad, assuming you don't need to have more than one Website in use at a time.  You can vary the Website used at run time.  It would also be okay to put the Website into every subclass.  This would not need all the complexity you show in option 3.  Finally, you could store the Website at the module level in the module(s) where the subclasses are defined.  This would have a bit of global variable smell, but might be expedient.

Comment: Yeah, option 2 is probably what I will go with. Thought about it some more, and it seems like a descent solution, especially if I only assign the class variables when I initialize the Website class.